# Is there a way to return custom 404 response in google storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using google storage to store product images.What i want is to show no-product-image.png image in case product has no image in storage, instead of 404 error code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) about the `gsutil web` command